# How to change screen resolution in MAcBook Pro 2013 15" Retina SSD? It fails when trying

Tags: display, macbook, macbook-pro, display-resolution

When trying to change to ANY different than maximum resolution built-in display of **MacBook Pro Summer 2013th Retina 15"** I get black screen and nothing more and every time I have to reboot the system with the button on the keyboard...
Could not you help me, please to fix it as the highest resolution (which is my current) is `2880x1800` which is disgusting on `15"`... I do not even understand why "smart" apple made this other than for marketing.... As nobody work on this resolutions neither under Mac OS X, nor under the other systems... Texts can be read only by insects and bacterias.... Thanks)

Comment: Nobody answers?

Comment: NO answer? Is anybody here to help?

Comment: They made it because OS X can handle resolution independence and it makes everything looks super crisp and sharp. I love my retina display, and not so much OS X anymore. I really hope I can find a way to change the resolution here... I was able to use the scale option in Ubuntu but Java apps still display at 2880x1800 and ubuntu starts to lag. No luck using Ubuntu 15.10... I've reverted to 14.04 but no luck so far either.